# Django REST framework url regex patterns not being matched

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am writing a RESTful API as an application for a django project. 
I have two end points in my application (with urls imported into the main project's urls.py), which are defined as shown below below:

### testrest/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'prices/(?P<ticker>[X]{1}[A-Z0-9]{3}:[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z09.-]{1,4})/?P<resolution>([0-9]{0,3})/$', views.historyPrices, name='prices'),
    url(r'chart/?P<name>([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]{8,12})/$s', views.chart, name='pchart'),
]
```

### testrest/views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response



# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET'])
def historyPrices(request, ticker, resolution=1):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            # do something
            return Response({'foo': 'foobar'})

        except Exception as e:
            print ('Error: {0}'.format(e))
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)     
    else:
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)



@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def chart(request, name=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':     
        if (name is not None):      
            try:
                # do something
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error:',e)
                return Response(status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)         

            return Response({'foo': 'bar')
        else:
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        # print(data)

        try:
            # do something
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)       

        except Exception as ex:
            print('Unhandled exception: {0}'.format(e))
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)


    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        print('Called with PUT')
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_501_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        print('Called with DELETE')
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_501_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)

    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I want to be able to call using the following urls (all of those shown below, return a 404 not found error:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/prices/XNAS:GOOG      (404)
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/prices/XNAS:GOOG/     (404)
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/prices/XNAS:GOOG/3    (404)
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/prices/XNAS:GOOG/3/   (404)

curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/prices?ticker=XNAS:GOOG      (404)
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/prices/?ticker=XNAS:GOOG&resolution=3    (404)
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/prices?ticker=XNAS:GOOG&resolution=3/   (404)
```

I now try to load a manually created chart (xyz) from the server:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/chart/xyz                 (404)
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/chart/xyz/                (404)
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/chart?name=xyz            (404)
```

I then try to POST (create) a new chart on the server:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{/* data */}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/chart     (404)
```

Why are the patterns not matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some typos in your `urls`. You are missing syntaxt for [regex named group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) for `<resolution>` and `<name>`. The following will match all of the above `404` fails:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'prices/?(?P<ticker>[X]{1}[A-Z0-9]{3}:[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z09.-]{1,4})?/?(?P<resolution>[0-9]{0,3})/?$', views.historyPrices, name='prices'),
    url(r'chart/?(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]{3,12})?/?$', views.chart, name='pchart')
]
```

Also, I changed the length of the `<name>` inside `pchart` url to be between 3 and 12 (do not know how you wanted to be).

Comment: I'm trying the prices API, it's almost there - at least there's no 404 any more - **BUT** the parameters are not being passed to the called function! :/

Comment: Both ticket and resolution are not passed?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In my view function, I give the resolution a default value of 1. However, no matter what values I use to call the API, resolution is recieved as an empty string, and ticker is received as a NoneType :/

Comment: I haven't started looking at the chart API yet. However, I want the name argument to be optional. The name is only looked at/used for GET calls, so I want to omit it for other REST verbs. I'll do the string validation only on the GET

Comment: I just test the `prices` API and params get passed to `view` flawlessly! I'm using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5 FYI

Comment: :( let me look closely and see if I have replicated everything needed in the snippet I provided on here ...

Comment: Are you extracting the args from the request object, or are they passed to the view function? **I'm not getting any arguments passed to my view function!**

Comment: It works either way (getting url parameters from `**kwargs` or passing them explicity to the `view`)